# Allegro 5 - Cosmic Protector Demo

Tags: allegro5

I'm new to C++ and Allegro 5 but have been able to follow tutorials online and am able to build and compile several smaller projects successfully.

I cannot however get the demo project named Cosmic Protector to run and would like to at least learn what is wrong.

Unfortunately, I can't give you much to go on.

A window opens briefly and then closes, leaving the console open with the message..
process 6400 exited with code 255

If you have this demo running in VC 2017 with the latest release of Allegro 5 (5.2.4) installed via Nuget, I'd like to know that even.

The source for this program is available at...
https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/tree/master/demos/cosmic_protector

Thank you, Jack

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's more likely that you get help if you edit your question and add a link to the mentioned example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks David. I've added a link. I figure this is a mega longshot but it's not even possible to register on the Allegro 5 forum due to the captcha being deprecated and needing updating.

Comment: The broken registration should be fixed as soon as our fearless leader gets around to reading his messages... ( https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/617789/1041789#target ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allegro example programs and demos are usually built with CMake alongside the Allegro library. I just tested the CMake build of Allegro 5 with VS2017 on Windows 10 and it builds the Cosmic Protector demo successfully. You have to move the allegro dlls into the same directory as the exe, but other than that it runs perfectly.

As to why it's not working for you, cosmic protector depends on a data directory that holds it's resources. The working directory may be wrong, which would cause it to be unable to find resources. The data dir needs to be copied alongside the executable.

You can set the working directory to $(OutDir) under Debugging in Project->Properties and then it should find any data in the same directory as the exe.

How are you building cosmic protector?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply as with your little nudge in the right direction I have the demo working now. I've described how in the post below as the info wouldn't fit into whats allowed for comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BugSquasher, I now have this working.

Here's how...

1. Start Visual Studio 2017
2. Create New Project of type Windows Console Application.
3. Name project CosmicProtector and save it in appropriate place on my HDD.
4. Disable precompiled headers and delete the any .h and .cpp
   files associated with the new project regarding precompiled headers.
   (for example pch.h)
5. Install Allegro 5.2.4 via Nuget.
6. In Visual Studio, navigate to Project Settings/Properties and ensure all
   Allegro addons are enabled.
7. Copy the Cosmic Protector SRC and Header files and paste them into my
   project directory.
8. Next in Visual Studio Project, Add the Source and Header files
   respectively.

Rather stupidly, the step I had missed and that your reply brought my attention to was...

9. Copy the data directory and paste this into my project directory in the 
   applicable location.
10. Now build...

The project built right away, except for some errors reported in Game.cpp, GUI.cpp and Render.cpp

**One error in Game.cpp, this being an instance of...**
error C4996 'snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

> To address this I have changed the instance of snprintf to sprintf_s.

**Three errors in GUI.cpp, were instances of...**
Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

> To address all of these I changed each instance of strcpy to strcpy_s.

**And one error in GUI.cpp, this being an instance of...**
error C4996 'snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

> To address this I have changed the instance of snprintf to sprintf_s.

**One error in Render.cpp, this being an instance of...**
error C4996 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

> To address this I have changed the instance of sprintf to sprintf_s.

Then build and it works:)

Thank you so much for your reply as I had moved on to other things but will find it very useful I think being able to build and run this demo.
It's only your reply that has brought me back to it and this time, I am successful:)